# Block Template not rendering

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.1 with the latest patches on PHP 5.6.

I am attempting to add a dynamic link to the `top.links` nav on the frontend.  I have managed to get to the point where my block seems to be loaded, but I do not see anything from my template.  Here are the relevant files:

## app/design/frontend/callcenter/default/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="callcenter_frontadmin/adminaccount" name="adminaccount" template="frontadmin/adminaccount.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
    </default>
</layout>
```

## app/design/frontend/callcenter/default/template/frontadmin/adminaccount.phtml

```
Hello, world!
```

My block is located in **app/code/local/Callcenter/Frontadmin/Block/Adminaccount.php** and is in fact being loaded (if I `die()` inside it, the site dies).  If I substitute the `<block>` tag for something else, like an `<action method="addLink"` whatever I add seems to appear in the correct place.

Caching is turned off.  Logging does not reveal anything suspicious in the logfiles.

EDIT: Here is my block

## app/code/local/Callcenter/Frontadmin/Block/Adminaccount.php

```
<?php

class Callcenter_Frontadmin_Block_Adminaccount extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `top.links` block is an instance of a template block. 
As such it doesn't automatically render child blocks. To render your block as a child of `top.links` you will have to edit the `page/template/links.phtml`template within your theme and add an explicit render like this:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('adminaccount');
```

...

gonna correct myself slightly, you should also be able to do this:

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>adminaccount</blockName></action>
    </reference>
```

within your existing `default` node

Comment: You were almost correct - I had to put both the action AND the block tag under the reference tag, and now I can see a new tag in my header.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1**

Try this way from xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
       <label>Blog</label>
       <url>/blog</url>
       <title>Blog</title>
       <prepare/>
       <urlParams/>
       <position>1</position>
       <liParams />
       <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
  </action>
  </reference>
  <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
  <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
</default>
```

We are utilising a method called `addLinks` from `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links.php`

```
/**
 * Add link to the list
 *
 * @param string $label
 * @param string $url
 * @param string $title
 * @param boolean $prepare
 * @param array $urlParams
 * @param int $position
 * @param string|array $liParams
 * @param string|array $aParams
 * @param string $beforeText
 * @param string $afterText
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links
 */
public function addLink($label, $url='', $title='', $prepare=false, $urlParams=array(),
    $position=null, $liParams=null, $aParams=null, $beforeText='', $afterText='')
{
    if (is_null($label) || false===$label) {
        return $this;
    }
    $link = new Varien_Object(array(
        'label'         => $label,
        'url'           => ($prepare ? $this->getUrl($url, (is_array($urlParams) ? $urlParams : array())) : $url),
        'title'         => $title,
        'li_params'     => $this->_prepareParams($liParams),
        'a_params'      => $this->_prepareParams($aParams),
        'before_text'   => $beforeText,
        'after_text'    => $afterText,
    ));

    $this->_addIntoPosition($link, $position);

    return $this;
}
```

I am ignoring your `app/code/local/Callcenter/Frontadmin/Block/Adminaccount.php` class, if you have any function inside there, then you will need to create a simple extension for better approach.

**OR like @Dave suggested**

You will have to call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('adminaccount');?>` from your `page/template/links.phtml` file.

I would still call it from xml, easy to maintain in future.

Comment: Tried that.  Still nothing being rendered.  I added the block to the original post.

Comment: ok, can you remove `<default>` and `</default>` completely. check my updated answer, also remove space from `<?xml version="1.0" ?>`

Comment: Removing the default tags did not result in the template being rendered, and additionally resulted in the two callout blocks that I had removed returning.

Comment: Sorry about that, you definitely need `<default>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `modman` to deploy your module, make sure that your Admin -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Template settings -> Allow symlinks is "Yes".

This can also be done with an SQL query:

```
update core_config_data \
    set value = '1' \
    where path = 'dev/template/allow_symlink';
```